# automatic panning google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a marker on google map v3, indicating a position of a vehicle. The marker moves, indicating the movement of the vehicle. How can I automatically pan the map, when marker tries to go out of the visible part of the map?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [getBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) function of the map to query for the boundaries. If your point is moving outside the boundaries, you can simply call [setCenter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) to update your map.